# JSpinner : how to display both numbers and text?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I would like to create a JSpinner which can take every possible `Double` value between a **specified minimum** and a **specified maximum**.

Also, the JSpinner should be able to **display a text instead of a specific value**. Let's say our JSpinner can take values from -1 to 10. I would like to display a text, e.g. "Auto", instead of -1 .

How to replace [image: Normal Jspinner : we can see "-1"] by 
[image: JSpinner where we can see "Auto" instead of "-1" even if Auto equals actually -1]

Here is the Model I wrote, but it seems not to be enough, because it says in JSpinner there is an error because the text is not a `Double`.

```
public class SpinnerSpecialModel
        extends AbstractSpinnerModel implements SpinnerMinMaxModel {

  public static final double DEFAULT_MINIMUM = 0.0;
  public static final double DEFAULT_MAXIMUM = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  public static final double DEFAULT_STEP = 1.0;
  public static final double DEFAULT_VALUE = 1.0;
  public static final double DEFAULT_SPECIAL_NUMBER = -1.0;
  public static final String DEFAULT_SPECIAL_TEXT = "Auto";

  private double maximum;
  private double minimum;
  private double stepSize;
  private double currentNumber;
  private double specialNumber;
  private String specialText;

  private Object m_Value;

  public SpinnerSpecialModel(double max, double min, double step, double num, 
        double specialNum, String specialTxt) {
    maximum = max;
    minimum = min;
    stepSize = step;
    currentNumber = num;
    specialNumber = specialNum;
    specialText = specialTxt;
    setAccurateValue(num);
  }

  public SpinnerSpecialModel(double specialNum, String specialTxt) {
    this(DEFAULT_MAXIMUM, DEFAULT_MINIMUM,
        DEFAULT_STEP, DEFAULT_VALUE, specialNum, specialTxt);
  }

  public SpinnerSpecialModel() {
    this(DEFAULT_SPECIAL_NUMBER, DEFAULT_SPECIAL_TEXT);
  }

  @Override
  public Object getValue() {
    if (currentNumber == specialNumber) {
      m_Value = specialText;
    }
    else {
      m_Value = currentNumber;
    }
    return m_Value;
  }

  @Override
  public void setValue(Object value) {
    setAccurateValue(value);
  }

  private void setAccurateValue(Object value) {
    if (value instanceof Double) {
      double doubleValue = (Double) value;
      if (doubleValue != currentNumber) {
        if (doubleValue == specialNumber) {
          currentNumber = specialNumber;
          m_Value = specialText;
        }
        else if (doubleValue > maximum) {
          currentNumber = maximum;
          m_Value = maximum;
        }
        else if (doubleValue < minimum) {
          currentNumber = maximum;
          m_Value = minimum;
        }
        else {
          currentNumber = doubleValue;
          m_Value = doubleValue;
        }
        fireStateChanged();
      }
    }

    if (value instanceof String) {
      String stringValue = (String) value;
      if (stringValue.equals(specialText)) {
        this.currentNumber = specialNumber;
        this.m_Value = specialText;
        fireStateChanged();
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Object getNextValue() {
    return getNewValue(+1);
  }

  @Override
  public Object getPreviousValue() {
    return getNewValue(-1);
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param direction
   * @return 
   */
  private Object getNewValue(int direction) {
    double newValue = currentNumber + direction * stepSize;
    setAccurateValue(newValue);
    return m_Value;
  }

  @Override
  public double getMaximum() {
    return maximum;
  }

  @Override
  public double getMinimum() {
    return minimum;
  }

  @Override
  public double getStepSize() {
    return stepSize;
  }

  @Override
  public void setMaximum(double max) {
    maximum = max;
  }

  @Override
  public void setMinimum(double min) {
    minimum = min;
  }

  @Override
  public void setStepSize(double step) {
    stepSize = step;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html).

Comment: good question - or in other words: no solution that comes easily :-) A SpinnerModel has no notion of not-in-model (like f.i. a ComboBoxModel), so you would probably need a custom extended model and a custom editor that can take the special value.

Comment: @mre Please don't answer if you just tell me to read Oracle Doc. If I ask here, it is because I can't see how to do it, aven after reading some documentation

Comment: @Pigrou, Easy with the attitude. How was I supposed to know that you've read the documentation? Most users are unaware of these tutorials, so I figured I'd attempt to guide you in the right direction. And I didn't provide an answer, it was a comment. And an appropriate one at that. Here, have a downvote.

Comment: We are supposed to help each other on this website... Thanks for the downvote ...

Comment: nice comments, but I slightly agreed with @mre

Comment: @Pigrou whats in_active, how do you want to set it as in_active, then switch to active, depends of

Comment: by default NumberSpinnerModel allows add non_numbers chars by default (big disadvantege of JFormattedTextField and Formatter), only to switch on with DocumentFilter, switch off DocumentFilter, nothing else

Comment: I didn't know that! The company where I work tweaked these components a lot so that I can't really do what I want with them ^^

Comment: I edited the whole question, now it is more understandable and I posted the Model I wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and proper way to do this is not as simple as just writing a model, but it is not very complicated. You actually need to write an `Editor` and a `Formatter` to have a true MVC spinner:

- A class that extends `JSpinner` : `SpecialValuesSpinner`.
- A class that implements SpinnerModel : `SpecialValuesSpinnerModel`
- A class that extends `DefaultEditor` and implements `DocumentListener` : `SpecialValuesSpinnerEditor`
- A class that extends `NumberFormatter` : `SpecialValuesSpinnerFormatter`

I am not going to show you the code for all classes, but here is basically what you have to do in each :

SpecialValuesSpinner :

```
public class SpecialValuesSpinner() extends SpinnerNumberModel {
    // in your constructor do this
    setModel(new SpecialValuesSpinnerModel(YOUR_SPECIAL_VALUES);
    setEditor(new SpecialValuesSpinnerEditor());
}
```

SpecialValuesSpinnerModel :

```
public class SpinnerSpecialValuesModel() extends JSpinner {
    // in this class you handle the fact that now, you have an
    // interval of values and a list of special values that are allowed.
    // here is what I did :
    @Override
    public Object getNextValue() {
        return incrValue(+1);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPreviousValue() {
        return incrValue(-1);
    }

    private Object incrValue(int dir) {
        // NB : BigDecimal here because this is what I used,
        // but use what you want in your model
        BigDecimal result = null;
        BigDecimal numberBD = new BigDecimal(getNumber().toString());
        BigDecimal stepSizeBD = new BigDecimal(getStepSize().toString());
        BigDecimal dirBD = new BigDecimal(dir);
        BigDecimal nextValue = numberBD.add(stepSizeBD.multiply(dirBD));

        TreeSet<BigDecimal> currentAllowedValues = new TreeSet<BigDecimal>();
        currentAllowedValues.addAll(m_SpecialValues);
        if (getMaximum() != null) {
          currentAllowedValues.add((BigDecimal) getMaximum());
        }
        if (getMinimum() != null) {
          currentAllowedValues.add((BigDecimal) getMinimum());
        }
        if (isIncludedInBounds(nextValue)) {
          currentAllowedValues.add(nextValue);
        }

        if (dir > 0) {
          try {
            result = currentAllowedValues.higher(numberBD);
          }
          catch (NoSuchElementException e) {}
        }
        else if (dir < 0) {
          try {
            result = currentAllowedValues.lower(numberBD);
          }
          catch (NoSuchElementException e) {}
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

In SpecialValuesSpinnerEditor, we use Document Listener to have autocompletion (easy to do, just search on SO).

```
public class SpecialValuesSpinnerEditor extends DefaultEditor implements DocumentListener {

    // You have to do in your contructor
    SpecialValuesSpinnerFormatter formatter = 
        new SpecialValuesSpinnerFormatter (spinner.getSpecialValues(), format);
    getTextField().setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(formatter));
}
```

And now, the most important, the Formatter which does conversion between user input (string) and numbers, and handle the model's display :

```
public class SpecialValuesSpinnerFormatter extends NumberFormatter {
    // Just override the methos StringToValue and ValueToString.
    // You can check here if the value is special
    // i.e you must display its special text instead. e.g. : "Auto" instead of -1
}
```

Comment: Any full examples? I'm running into the same issue. I tried the changes but what i'm seeing is that when a user types in a number it will let them type something over the maximum. When I take the default editor out it is ok but then i'm not able to change the one value to "AUTO"

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve that by implementing your own [`SpinnerModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerModel.html) and supplying that as argument to the `JSpinner` constructor.

Comment: Do you have any examples or ideas for a JSpinner without boundaries (i.e. not like the months in Oracle Docs demos) ?

Comment: I think extending [`AbstractSpinnerModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractSpinnerModel.html) would be the way to go; your subclass should keep track of the `currentvalue`; the `nextValue` will always be 1 higher than `currentValue`; the `previousValue` would always be 1 lower than `currentValue` (unless you're at 0, then it would be "auto").

Comment: @both [see code example about](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Aprogramtotestspinners.htm)